# Can't recognize circuit element in old clock mechanism

Tags: switches, mechanical-assembly

I am spending my free time thinking of how to make an old clock in my hometown working again. Here is a picture of the mechanism. I can't recognize the marked parts. Hope somebody of you can.

[image]

In this photo one can see two unknown elements of the same type, as well as element marked with an arrow. This looks like a metal pin that makes contact with unlnown part.

Comment: Thank god we have no "smell over ip" protocols...

Comment: xD By the way, is there any cleaner I can use to remove the source of the smell?

Comment: @PlasmaHH If that stuff is from pigeons, there are [worse things](http://medicinereport.com/article/4-diseases-you-can-catch-from-pigeons) than the smell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, these look like [microswitches](http://sensing.honeywell.com/micro_switch_v7_basic-switch_v7-1c17d8-263_highres.jpg). [Microswitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniature_snap-action_switch) is a genericized trade name (Honeywell) for smallish snap-action switches often used in electromechanical equipment for limit switches and so on. Overall dimensions, actuator style, and electrical ratings distinguish different models within a given manufacturer's line.

[image]

Check a distributor such as Digikey.com for plenty of datasheets from various manufacturers.

Answer (score 3):

Standard sized microswitches (which aren't actually micro-sized!). They are available with [different shapes of lever](http://uk.farnell.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?catalogId=15001&langId=44&storeId=10151&categoryId=700000006205&st=microswitch&pageSize=25&showResults=true&pf=110021329) and even roller connected to the switch, so that they may be operated by moving equipment or cams - clearly here, to turn the winding mechanism off at the right time.

[image]

Connections to them are usually standard spade clips, visible in your photo.

Thankfully the switch elements are sealed from the elements and pigeons...

Comment: Related to the OP's question, I have few dozen microswitches that are probably 20+ years old. They're fine, but the external terminals are dirty and appear to have become coated with something varnish like. What's an easy way to clean them? The actual switch contacts are fine. For obvious reasons, I'd rather not use sandpaper or something abrasive. I have considered purple Zep, but having seen what it did to the paint on a greasy old industrial instrument I have, probably not a good idea.